# Using wget script snippet with batch file to invoke PUT

Tags: rest, batch-file, wget

I'd like to invoke a RESTful PUT request to an endpoint via Batch File on my computer using WGET but it doesn't appear to be working. I've been using Postman and it gave me the WGET snippet so I went on and used it to my batch script but it doesnt work.

```
wget --no-check-certificate --quiet \
  --method PUT \
  --timeout=0 \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --body-data '{
    "receipt_id": xxxx,
    "status": "xxxx",
    "amount_cents": xxxx,
    "reason": "xxxx",
    "reason_description": "xxxxx"
}' \
   'https://website.com/update_status?app_key=XXXXXXX&utoken=XXXXXX'
```

When I tried to run it it gave me '--method is not a recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file '--timeout' is not a recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

I already downloaded the wget exe and made sure to ran the batch script on the same path as the wget executable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The line continuation character is `^`, not ``\``. imo line continuation is pretty much always a bad idea. Also, I'm not expecting those single quotes to work since cmd really only plays nice with double quotes.

Comment: Do you suggest replacing \ to ^? I tried to do this but it doesnt work

Comment: I recommend putting everything all on one line. I also recommend replacing all of the `'`s with `"`s and all of the `"`s with `\"`s. You might also want to try using `curl` since that's come with Windows for the last four years. Also, you don't have any line continuation characters on the body data section, which will absolutely break things.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

I do not know if this is sole reason of malfunction, but your options are not compliant with [Wget manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) namely:

- you have elected to use `--method PUT` when manual stipulates
  `--method=HTTP-Method` (note `=` sign)
- you have elected to use `--header 'Content-Type: application/json'` when manual stipulates `--header=header-line` (note `=` sign)
- you have elected to use `--body-data '{` when manual stipulates `--body-data=Data-String` (note `=` sign)

You have use `timeout` in way compliant with manual, however please keep in mind that

> Unless you know what you are doing, it is best not to change the
> default timeout settings.

Also usage of `--quiet` is counterproductive for finding reasons of malfunction, if you have to use it AT ANY PRICE you should have *correctly working* `wget` command before applying it.